# 3 spans next to each other alignment

Tags: html, css

I have 3 spans. The first two contain an icons(pictures) 16x16px. The third span contain long text. The problem is that when the text is too long it appears in the second line too, but right at the beginning of line... It needs to be aligned and starts on the same place as the first line. These 3 spans can not be wrapped to any div or so. Is there any possibility how  to achieve this. Look at the picture and here is sample page `spans example` http://jsfiddle.net/P76Sg/

[image]

Comment: You can put `display:table-cell` to the `span` elements - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P76Sg/1/)

Comment: How can I miss that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the effect you are looking for by using a float and overflow trick. Contain the two icons within their own `<div>` and float that left. Then hide the overflow of your text element and it will always clear the icons but take of the rest of the available width:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="icons">
        <span><img /></span>
        <span><img /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
SSSScontent 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 dfssssss
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cont{width:280px}
.icons{float:left}
.text{background-color:red; overflow:hidden}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P76Sg/7/)

---

Or take a different approach and have the spans display as table cells:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P76Sg/8/)

Answer (score 0):

As*Vucko* suggested, we can use display:table-cell.
Or we can use `<table>` structure to create as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding some left margin to the 3rd span:

```
margin-left:15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
<div style="width:280px;">
    <span style="background-color:#333333; display: table-cell;">
        <img style = "width:16px; height=16px;"/>
    </span>

    <span style="background-color:#F111FF; display: table-cell;">
        <img style = "width:16px; height=16px;"/>
    </span>

    <span style="background-color:red; display: table-cell;">
SSSScontent 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 dfssssss
    </span>
</div>
```